# Automated way to get every table that's used in any View - INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE is incomplete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see every table in my Azure SQL database that is referenced in a View.

One would think this would work:

```
select distinct table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
```

But the table list is incomplete.  There are tables missing, which I can manually verify are being called in Views.

Googling, I see others with the same issue, as well as people saying not to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, because they're not accurate.  Note: Nothing specific to Azure SQL, just in general - posts saying it's inaccurate.

I see references to using sys.objects instead.  But if I run

```
exec sp_helptext 'information_schema.view_table_usage
```

I see that the inaccurate view, is itself referencing sys.objects

*Is* there an automated, accurate way to see which tables are being used in a View, within a given database?

Comment: Thank you - sys.sql_expression_dependencies helped me narrow it down.  information_schema.view_table_usage was missing the User-Defined tables utilized in Views,. But in my particular case I don't need those anyway, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`, which is generally more reliable.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
WHERE d.referencing_id IN (SELECT v.object_id FROM sys.views)
```